# Select random rows with no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select a random amount of rows but also ensure that the rows don't contain duplicate Image values:

```
ImgID   Image

1637    PM1371564839.jpg    
1638    PM1371564839.jpg    
1639    PM1371564840.jpg    
1640    PM1371564840.jpg    
1641    PM1371564840.jpg    
1642    PM1371564841.jpg    
1643    PM1371564842.jpg    
1644    PM1371564842.jpg    
1645    PM1371564842.jpg    
1646    PM1371564843.jpg    
1647    PM1371564843.jpg
```

I have done a  - `select top 25 percent * from Table  order by newid();`  This works for the random side of things but it brings back duplicate.  I have tried a distinct  but it doesnt like the order by part.  Basically is there a better way to show just show a random 3 Images that are not duplicates.

Comment: Select random values from a subselect of distinct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you have multiple images with different ImgID

maybe you want something like this to get unique images

```
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT * FROM 
( 
  SELECT 
    max(imgID) imgID,  
    Image
  FROM [table]
  GROUP BY [Image]
) x
ORDER BY newid();
```

Comment: +1 . . . This is the only solution that guarantees that image is distinct.  You should, however, add in a `group by` in the subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Grzegorz Gierlik seems to have got it right as well. However, this one may be better (once fixed) in that it also supplies the distinct names with IDs.

Comment: SELECT TOP (25) PERCENT *
FROM  (SELECT MAX(imgID) imgID , Image FROM Table  GROUP BY Image) x
ORDER BY NEWID()     This only shows 1 image,  even if i change to top 90 percent still shows the one row

Comment: @user2498219: Seems to work well in [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/928b0/6).

Comment: Yes you are right ,  I am sorry i dont know what I have done wrong,  Let me look at it again ,  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like:

```
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT
 *
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT image FROM table) -- only unique image values
ORDER BY
 newid() -- random sort
```

Keep in mind that his query has a few issues:

- Subselect reads the whole table and makes `DISTINCT` on it (probably need index).
- It's hard to JOIN other columns from `TABLE` table (no PK which would destroy `DISTINCT`) in outer `SELECT`.

Here is more readable version of above query:

```
;WITH unique_images AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT image FROM TABLE
)
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT
  *
FROM
  unique_images
ORDER BY
  new_id()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Northwind
GO


select top 10 CustomerID , OrderID
from
(
select distinct CustomerID, OrderID from dbo.[Orders]
) as derived1

order by newid()
```

Mapped to yours:

```
select top 25 PERCENT ImgID , Image
from
(
select distinct ImgID , Image from dbo.[MyTable]
) as derived1

order by newid()
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
SELECT TOP 3 ImgID, Image
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ImgID, Image
      FROM #MyTABLE
      )sub
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/928b0/2/0)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  You are right I am looking for a random number of unique images.  The query you supplied complained about not having a group by clause which I added but that listed just one image , and I need a random selection of images